# CSS Footer - Left hand items are higher than right hand items

Tags: css, position, inline

I am trying to make a CSS footer but have ran into some major problems.

Here is what my footer looks like

```
Logo Games Database
                                                          Home About Contact
```

Where the logo is an image at the far left. Games Database appears in text. Both appear about 1 line above

I would like my footer to look like this

```
Logo Games Database                                       Home About Contact
```

Alright, I decided to post the full HTML output I received from the browser. I removed the data turbo links and a bunch of the rows in my table because I wanted to be as concise as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

    <head>
      <title>Games</title
     </head>

  <body>

<header class='navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse'>
  <div class='navbar-inner'>
    <div class='container'>
      <a href="/games" id="logo">Games Database</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class='nav pull-right'>
          <li><a href="/games">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>


          <li><a href="/users/38">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="/users/favorites">Favorites</a></li>
          <li><a data-method="delete" href="/signout" id="signout" rel="nofollow">Sign Out</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


<h1>Games Database</h1>

<table>

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th id = 'title_id'><a class="current asc" href="/games?direction=desc&amp;sort=title">Title</a></th>
    <th id = 'console_id'><a href="/games?direction=asc&amp;sort=console">Console</a></th>
    <th id = 'genre_id'><a href="/games?direction=asc&amp;sort=genre">Genre</a></th>
    <th id = 'release_id'><a href="/games?direction=asc&amp;sort=release+date">Release Date</a></th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody> 


<tr>
  <td id = 'title'>Animal Crossing</td>
  <td id = 'console'>Gamecube</td>
  <td id = 'genre'>Life Simulation</td>
  <td id = 'released_on'>2001</td>


    <div>
      <td><a href="/games/36" id="show">Show</a></td>
      <td><a href="/games/36/edit" id="edit">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/36" id="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </div>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td id = 'title'>Donkey Kong Country</td>
  <td id = 'console'>Super Nintendo</td>
  <td id = 'genre'>Platform</td>
  <td id = 'released_on'>1994</td>

    <div>
      <td><a href="/games/35" id="show">Show</a></td>
      <td><a href="/games/35/edit" id="edit">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a data-method="delete" href="/games/35" id="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
    </div>

</tr>

 </tbody>

</table>


<p>
  <a href="/games/new" id="submit">Add a new game</a>
</p>



<ul class = 'footer'>
<li><img alt="83ec69e47df392e6856aca4a7a276e9b" id="footer-logo" src="http://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/59245571/disp/83ec69e47df392e6856aca4a7a276e9b.jpg" />
    <li id = "footer-left">Games Database</li>

    <div id = 'footer-center'>
      <li><a href="/games" id="links">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about" id="links">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/static_pages/contact" id="links">Contact</a></li>
    </div>

    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS file

```
.footer {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;

  li {
    display: inline;
  }

  #footer-center {
    float:right;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    margin-left: 980px;
    color: black;
   }

 #footer-logo {
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
  } 
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  &:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
}

#links {
  color: black;
}
```

I've tried just about everything. I've tried setting the footer to fixed, relative and absolute. I tried setting the bottom property to 0, fiddling around with it, even in the negatives.

I tried margin-top and margin bottom on the left hand side, but just cannot figure this out.

I even tried to post it on jsfiddle, but I had no luck because I can't figure out how to get that site to work.

I'm using bootstrap.

Help is appreciated.

I finally got the CSS to show in CSSDesk, but I'm not sure I trust it, because it doesn't render bootstrap. Anyways, here goes

http://cssdesk.com/eL2J2

Comment: Please edit your post with a fiddle demonstrating the issue http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: That's not pure HTML, we *cannot* reproduce your situation. `some content` is not descriptive at all, **what do they represent**. You aren't using Bootstrap here, you provide more code than necessary. This is a horrid question

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of CMS to get your values, hence the % tags.  If you could tag this question with that CMS it would be much appreciated.

Comment: that tag is part of ruby, it means embedded ruby and is used in HTML files.

Comment: That helps, but `some content` is not descriptive at all, what do they represent? And please only include the *relevant* HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't wrap three of your list elements in a div the way you currently have it. Here is a potential solution:

-- the plain CSS --

```
.footer { position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: auto; }
#footer-left { float: left; }
#footer-right { float: right; }
.footer ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.footer li { display: inline-block; list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.footer a { color: black; }
#footer-logo { height: 30px; width: 50px; }
#game { float: right; }
```

-- the HTML --

```
<div class="footer">
<ul id="footer-left">
<li><img alt="83ec69e47df392e6856aca4a7a276e9b" id="footer-logo" src="http://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/59245571/disp/83ec69e47df392e6856aca4a7a276e9b.jpg" />
<li id="game">Games Database</li>
</ul>
<ul id="footer-right">
<li><a href="/games">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/static_pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

No idea how this would be implemented in bootstrap, but this should give you a basic idea for how to structure your footer.

Comment: I used divs the wrong way. Thanks for pointing that out. That helped solve my problem